# Button to remove a dynamically created list element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an ordered list in HTML:

```
<ol id ="list">
</ol>
```

which gets added to using JQuery/javascript:

```
$(function (){
    $("#click-me").click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        i++;

        var list = $("#list");
        var name = $("#colleague-select option:selected").text();
        var remove = "<button type='button' class='remove-me'> X </button>";
        var entry = "<li>" + name + remove+ "</li>";
        entry.id = "entryid" + i;

        list.append(entry);

        return false;
    });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to allow a user to **remove an entry in the list by clicking its corresponding button "X"**. This is the code I've come up with, but it's not working:

```
$(function (){
   $(".remove-me").click(function(e){

       var list = $("#list");
       var entry = e.parent(); //find parent entry of clicked "X" button
       list.remove(entry);  //remove entry from list
   });
});
```

Any help guys? I am fairly new to JQuery so an explanation of your answer code would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for binding events to dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on('click', ".remove-me", function(e){
    var entry = $(this).parent(); 
    entry.remove();  //remove entry from list
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `parent` element

```
$(function (){
   $(document).on("click", ".remove-me", function(e){
       $(this).parent().remove(); //find parent entry of clicked "X" button
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A foolproof way is add the event to the button

```
<button type='button' onclick='removeMe(this);' class='remove-me'> X </button>
```

and on js

```
function removeMe(e)
{
   $(e).parent().remove();
}
```